# What's the difference between `raw_input()` and `input()` in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

What is the difference between `raw_input()` and `input()` in Python 3?

Comment: How do you make a program that takes input both Python 2 and Python 3 compatible?

Comment: To do that you try to set `input` to `raw_input` and ignore name errors.

Comment: Look up the 'six' library for python 2 and 3 compatibility.

Comment: What I do is just writing Python 2 code in "try:" block and Python 3 code in "except NameError:" block.

Answer (score 452, accepted):

The difference is that `raw_input()` does not exist in Python 3.x, while `input()` does.  Actually, the old `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()`, and the old `input()` is gone, but can easily be simulated by using `eval(input())`.  (Remember that `eval()` is evil. Try to use safer ways of parsing your input if possible.)

Comment: "What's the difference between `raw_input`...?" - "The difference is that there's no `raw_input`." ...Quite a drastic difference, I'd say!

Comment: In Python 2 I guess they assumed programmers wanted to actually "execute" as a command the user input, since initially (I guess) requesting input from user might only be for that. But when they realised programmers might also want to get the "raw" input, they designed another function called "raw_input". In Python 3 they noticed what stupid was that and simply deleted the original input default's execution, yielding only one simple function.

Comment: Repl.it, running Py3.5.1 has raw_input() as a keyword.

Comment: It needs to be said that `eval` (and `exec`) should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. And of course that advice also applies to the old Python 2 `input`.

Comment: @PM2Ring I added a warning to the answer.  Of course there are valid use cases for both `eval()` and `exec()`, but you first need to understand why you shouldn't use `eval()` before deciding to use it.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is still being tweaked, the docs show that Py34 and Py36  have seen changes in base int handling: [link]https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 199):

In Python **2**, `raw_input()` returns a string, and `input()` tries to run the input as a Python expression.

Since getting a string was almost always what you wanted, Python 3 does that with `input()`. As Sven says, if you ever want the old behaviour, `eval(input())` works.

Comment: You should add that Python 3 does not have `raw_input()`.

Comment: what is the use of running input as python expression?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain, probably it was intended for entering numbers. But it is totally unsafe.

Answer (score 125):

## Python 2:

- `raw_input()` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string.
- `input()` first takes the `raw_input()` and then performs an `eval()` on it as well.

The main difference is that `input()` expects a syntactically correct python statement where `raw_input()` does not.

## Python 3:

- `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` so now `input()` returns the exact string.
- Old `input()` was removed.

If you want to use the old `input()`, meaning you need to evaluate a user input as a python statement, you have to do it manually by using `eval(input())`.

Answer (score 31):

In Python 3, `raw_input()` doesn't exist which was already mentioned by Sven.

In Python 2, the `input()` function evaluates your input.

**Example:**

```
name = input("what is your name ?")
what is your name ?harsha

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("what is your name ?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'harsha' is not defined
```

In the example above, Python 2.x is trying to evaluate harsha as a variable rather than a string. To avoid that, we can use double quotes around our input like "harsha":

```
>>> name = input("what is your name?")
what is your name?"harsha"
>>> print(name)
harsha
```

**raw_input()**

The raw_input()` function doesn't evaluate, it will just read whatever you enter.

**Example:**

```
name = raw_input("what is your name ?")
what is your name ?harsha
>>> name
'harsha'
```

**Example:**

```
 name = eval(raw_input("what is your name?"))
what is your name?harsha

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    name = eval(raw_input("what is your name?"))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'harsha' is not defined
```

In example above, I was just trying to evaluate the user input with the `eval` function.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to add a little more detail to the explanation provided by everyone for the **python 2 users**. `raw_input()`, which, by now, you know that evaluates what ever data the user enters as a string. This means that python doesn't try to even understand the entered data again. All it will consider is that the entered data will be string, whether or not it is an actual string or int or anything.

While `input()` on the other hand tries to understand the data entered by the user. So the input like `helloworld` would even show the error as '`helloworld is undefined`'.

In conclusion, for **python 2**, to enter a string too you need to enter it like '`helloworld`' which is the common structure used in python to use strings.

Answer (score 5):

If You want to ensure, that your code is running with python2 and python3, add `input()` function at the beginning of your script:

```
from sys import version_info
if version_info.major == 3:
    pass
elif version_info.major == 2:
    try:
        input = raw_input
    except NameError:
        pass
else:
    print ("Unknown python version - input function not safe")
```